# Wait for promise in non async function Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, database, asynchronous, discord.js

I'm trying to check if a player is already in my database and if not send him a custom discord message.

I have an async function that awaits the response of my database (I am using supabase). If the user does not exist it returns false, else it returns true.

```
async function doesUserExist(user_id:string){
    let id = await database.GetUserInfo(user_id)
    if (id == null){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This info is checked when a message is send to the bot. In the code snippet below I use the response of the async function to determine if I should send a discord message. However the code snippet never runs even when the output of the function should be true.

```
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    if(!doesUserExist(message.author.id)) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

I presume this has something to do with async functions returning promise and therefore the if statement just never fires. I am however fairly new to typescript (and javascript).

the packages I am using are

- @supabase/supabase-js@2.1.0
- discord.js@14.6.0
- typescript@4.9.3

If you have any further questions regarding my issue feel free to ask them.

Comment: Yep, it should be `async (message) => {` and you should resolve the promise first, i.e `if(! await doesUserExist(message.author.id)) {`

Comment: Thank you very much @Zslot I did not know u could pass an async when creating a function that way. Many thanks for the quick respons.

Comment: The second parameter for `client.on` is a function. It doesn't care if it's a synchronous function (the default) or an asynchronous function (specified by the `async` keyword).